# I Can't Set Height Of Bottom Bar

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm using roughike's bottombar library. I have one view pager and one bottombar view. My goal is set a little height for bottom bar and set a big height for viewpager. But when I use this code, I cant see bottombar and only viewpager appearing.

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mainViewPager"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        app:bb_tabXmlResource="@xml/bottom_bar"
        app:bb_behavior="shifting"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Also I'm sure i set up bottombar.

[image: only viewpager appearing]

----Edit----

Removed relative layout and set weight. But there is a little white space between view pager and bottombar as you can see in the picture.

Now code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/mainViewPager"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="2">

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
    android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    app:bb_tabXmlResource="@xml/bottom_bar"
    app:bb_behavior="shifting"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: little space]

Comment: remove relativeLayouts and make sure viewpager is not overlaying bottombar. u may use layout:weights for lineralayout

Comment: try using `RelativeLayout` for the parent view (instead of `LinearLayout`) and `android:layout_alignParentBottom` for `BottomBar`.

Comment: @uguboz i edited the post. Onik wait for it

Comment: @Onik When i do this, it doesnt change. Sams as the first picture

Comment: Remove the wrapper `RelativeLayout` and use "layout_above="@id/bottomBar"" attribute for `ViewPager`'s `RelativeLayout`. Actually, if you're not going to use anything else inside of both `RelativeLayout`s, you don't need them at all.

Comment: when u use weight attr u should use layout:height="match_parent" of the both Bottombar and viewpager.

Comment: @uguboz No. It should be `layout:height="0dp"`.

Comment: Correct :) it is my fault